# How to relaunch an app with Compose within the same test

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-espresso

Essentially I am just looking for an equivalent of https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/1500637-terminate combined with https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/1500467-launch.

I am writing a instrumental test in Android in which I want to close the app as a whole and than start it again, to check if the flow is correct when restarting the app, like it happens a lot in real life. However I can not get it working. I have this line of code:

```
@get:Rule
val app = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()
```

To close the app, I tried using this:

```
val device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())

device.pressRecentApps()

val displayWidth = device.displayWidth
val displayHeight = device.displayHeight

val startX = displayWidth / 2
val startY = (displayHeight * 0.6).toInt() // Start from 80% of the screen height
val endY = (displayHeight * 0.2).toInt() // End at 20% of the screen height

delay(500L)

device.swipe(startX, startY, startX, endY, 3)
```

This LOOKS like it's closing the app, but from testing it, it still keeps the app in memory. When I use this code, I noticed another app is launched, but next to the existing app because it is not closed:

```
val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context
val intent = context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)!!

// From ChatGPT
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) // Clear the task stack
context.startActivity(intent)
```

Code is executed for a new app, but the UI is still from the old app. This could be because I am using the `app` variable to do stuff. I tried assigning a new `app` variable, but then I got errors because it is not setup.

How can I relaunch a new instance of the app?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do it. The possibility of this action does not depend on Compose or XML layouts, though.

Thinking logically, you need to

1. close the app
2. relaunch the app
3. check if everything works as expected.

To move further with the answer, we need to define the scope of responsibility our steps induce. So, the first two steps do not concern your app at all - those are pure Android OS interactions. The third step is the only step concerning your app.

Now, following this logic, we should be able to proceed with using UI Automator to handle OS interactions and Espresso or another framework to handle the app testing, but the issue is that this logic is flawed, and somehow no one writes about that anywhere.

UI Automator doesn't share the same context with your other testing frameworks, thus, using it to manipulate OS functions and then proceeding with your usual testing via `@get:Rule`-created apps is not possible.

When you start using UI Automator in your case, you are limited to the UI Automator API only. Of course, you can also use other frameworks here - but their tests will be independent of one another, along with instances of activities and apps they create. This means that the app opened by `UiDevice` or `UiDevice2` objects is not accessible for testing by other means. The vice versa(app created via `@get:Rule` to be manipulated by UI Automator) works, but as far as I tested, it is somehow limited and utterly pointless in your case since you would have to use UI Automator API either way.

When you understand and accept all the above, you can start coding.

This is mostly pseudo code that emulates the situation and the code from the documentation:

```
private const val _appId = "Your application id"

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ChangeTextBehaviorTest2 {


private lateinit var device: UiDevice

// You can do all the preparation before the actual test
@Before
fun startMainActivityFromHomeScreen() {
  // Initialize UiDevice instance
  device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())

  // Start from the home screen
  device.pressHome()

  // Wait for launcher
  val launcherPackage: String = device.launcherPackageName
  assertThat(launcherPackage, notNullValue())
  device.wait(
    Until.hasObject(By.pkg(launcherPackage).depth(0)),
    LAUNCH_TIMEOUT
  )

  // Launch the app
  val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
  val intent = context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(
  _appId).apply {
    // Clear out any previous instances
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
  }
  context.startActivity(intent)

  // Wait for the app to appear
  device.wait(
    Until.hasObject(By.pkg(_appId).depth(0)),
    LAUNCH_TIMEOUT
    )
 

  // Here you would have to do all the things you wanted to do with your app
  // before shutting it down and opening it once more
  // for example lets press some button

  device.findObject(
    By.text("Some button").clazz("android.widget.Button")
  )?.apply{
    // Lets click the found button
    click()
  }

  device.findObject(By.text("Some search").clazz("android.widget.EditText"))?.apply{
  // Lets type some search query
  waitForExists(TIMEOUT)
  setText("some query")
  device.pressEnter()
}
   

  // repeat the code above for all the elements you need to interact with
  // before closing the app
  ...
  // Here, close the opened app with your code
  ...

  // Here reopen the app with the code above once more(you can create a separate method for that)

  }

  // And now write actual test but using UI Automator API
  @Test
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun doTheRelaunchTest() {
// here find all the needed UI elements and interact with them in the needed way using UI Automator API

// do assertions like this for every step you need
    Assert.assertTrue(device.hasObject(By.pkg(_appId)))

    
}

// the test is ready and functional - the app was dead and relaunched and you indeed tested this case
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you Pavlo, since last 4 days I was struggling with for this.

Answer (score 0):

*I think* your best bet is to do this via adb commands actually. You could use  [UiAutomation.executeShellCommand](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiAutomation.html#executeShellCommand(java.lang.String)) method, which is available from API 21:

```kotlin
fun adbCommand(cmd: String) {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
    return
  }
  val automation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().uiAutomation
  val pfd = automation.executeShellCommand(cmd)
  try {
    FileInputStream(pfd.fileDescriptor).readBytes()
  } catch (e: Throwable) {
    // ignored
  }
  pfd.close()
}
```

And then use it like this to kill and restart the app:

```kotlin
adbCommand("am force-stop com.package.name")
adbCommand("am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.MainActivity")
```

Answer (score 0):

In jetpack compose testing, you need to add dependancy for UiDevice,

```
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.3.0"
```

Then, follow below code.

```
private val appLaunchTime
    get() = 3000L

private val appId: String = "appId" 

@Test
fun closeAppAndRelaunch() {  
     device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
     device.pressHome()
     val launcherPackage: String = device.launcherPackageName
     Assert.assertThat(launcherPackage, CoreMatchers.notNullValue())
     device.wait(
        Until.hasObject(By.pkg(launcherPackage).depth(0)),
            appLaunchTime
        )
     // Launch the app
     val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
     val intent =
         context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(appId)?.apply {
            // Clear out any previous instances
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
        }
     context.startActivity(intent)
     device.wait(
         Until.hasObject(By.pkg(appId).depth(0)),
            appLaunchTime
        )
    composeTestRule.waitForIdle()
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag(TestTags.SPLASH_LOGO).assertIsDisplayed()
}
```

And thats it.. :)

Answer (score -1):

alternatively try closing the app by simulating home button press.  Try sending the app to the background to ensure it's closed before relaunching.

> val device =
> UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
> device.pressHome()

Then relaunch the app with a new instance, you can use an Intent to start the main activity of your app. Wait for some time and then reinitialize the UI test